# Sitecore PowerShell Remoting: how to

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

**Environment details**: Sitecore 10 Azure PAAS hosting

I am trying to automate a few things in an already running Sitecore set-up.
For that, I wanted to utilize Sitecore Powershell remoting.

I have gone through different blogs and videos. Still, I have a few questions:

1. Almost all sample scripts start with `Import-Module -Name SPE` such as [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting).
   So, from wherever this script has to be executed, the **SPE** module should be accessible.
   So, I can conclude that this script will be present in Sitecore.
   Is my understanding correct?
2. But then why do we need to provide the Connection URI, as mentioned [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting), if the script is being executed on the Sitecore instance?
3. If the script is being executed outside, how Sitecore is identifying the methods being exposed, as shown in the [video](https://youtu.be/fGvT8eDdWrg?t=86)

It would be of great help if the community can help me to understand how things work under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore PowerShell Remoting (SPE Remoting) is broken up into two parts.

Part 1: Remoting web services installed in the CM/Standalone instance

These services are distributed with the packages provided for SPE but do require  patches to enable/configure the services. For example, the "remoting" endpoint is disabled by default.

Part 2: Windows PowerShell module

The module is something that would be installed on a developer workstation, CI/CD server, or container and is the same environment where the script is executed.

---

So back to your question.

- `Import-Module -Name SPE` is contained with a script running outside of Sitecore.
- The connection URI is the location of your running instance of Sitecore (e.g. https://demo.dev.local).
- The SPE module includes commands like `Invoke-RemoteScript` in which you embed the script to be executed inside a Sitecore context.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just one more thing. Windows PowerShell module is the same one which we get on a new PC with Windows?

Comment: Windows PowerShell 5.1 is typically on a new PC. The SPE Remoting module is something you must install.

Comment: Thank Michael for helping. I was getting confused.